# baseParam for extjs paging

Tags: extjs, pagination, extjs4.1

I am using datefields and comboboxes to make a selection to load a store. When the store is loaded into a grid i have a paging toolbar. So far so good.

When the user clicks on the next page the pagingtoolbar is not sending the data from the datefields with it. I read something about baseparams but this aint working.

I use EXTJS 4.1

This is my store:

```
    NL.commListDetails = new Ext.data.Store({
    model: 'stepDetails',
    pageSize: 20,
    loadMask: false,
    sortOnLoad: true,

    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: detailURL,
        startParam: '',
        limitParam: '',
        pageParam: '',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'slaevents',
            totalProperty: 'slaevents[0].totalCount'
        }
    },
    baseParams: {fromDate:NL.startDate},
    autoLoad: false
});
```

And here is the paging toolbar

```
 bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        store: NL.commListDetails,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: 'Displaying record {0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: "No records to display",

    }),
```

I need to send fromDate, endDate with the paging. Both available in NL.startDate and NL.endDate. How can i send this when i click on next page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration of baseParams for the store. To send extra params you should use the extraParams configuration for the ajax proxy.

```
proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        ....
        extraParams: {fromDate:NL.startDate},
        ..
    },
```

Also defining the params when creating the store will mean they are static, so they won;t change if you modify the datefields or comboboxes...

So a fix will be to listen to the change event on the combobox or datefield and reset the extra params:

```
change: function(this,value){
      NL.commListDetails.getProxy().getExtraParams().comboName = value;
 }
```

**Edit**
I stand corrected. There is a baseParams but it's on elementloader and that is called only when load is directly invoked, which i think is not the case for the paging toolbar which uses loadPage. I might be wrong on this one, but i'm using extraparams and it works ok.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. When i do this i get NL.commListDetails.getProxy().getExtraParams is not a function

Comment: my mistake, there is no method to get all params , you can replace it with setExtraParam(comboName,value); http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-method-setExtraParam